# Jbutton not working on click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to make battleship java game and for start i created two jbutton grids and used to arrays to keep check on the jbuttons.
On clicking a jbutton since i have kept all jbuttons empty the color of jbutton should change.
A lot is still left to add to make it a full game but the basic change of colour of jbutton on click isnt working.
This is the first file which calls my mpanel file where all work is done.

```
    mPanel mPanel = new mPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(mPanel); //to add panel

    frame.pack(); //
```

//here is the 2nd file

```
 GridListener gridListener = new GridListener();
int count=0;
//count is kept to keep a check if itsplayer1 or 2's turn 

public mPanel()
{

title = new JLabel("BATTLESHIP!");
titlePanel = new JPanel();
titlePanel.add(title);
gridButton = new JButton[10][10];
gridButton1 = new JButton[10][10];
gridPanel = new JPanel();
gridPanel1= new JPanel();
gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
gridPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
for (int r = 0; r < gridButton.length; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < gridButton[r].length; c++)
    {
    gridButton[r][c] = new JButton();
    gridButton[r][c].setBackground(COLOR_UNCLICKED);
    gridButton[r][c].setEnabled(true);
    gridButton[r][c].addActionListener(gridListener);
    gridPanel.add(gridButton[r][c]);
    }
gridPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
for (int r = 0; r < gridButton1.length; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < gridButton1[r].length; c++)
    {
    gridButton1[r][c] = new JButton();
    gridButton1[r][c].setBackground(COLOR_UNCLICKED);
    gridButton1[r][c].setEnabled(true);
    gridButton1[r][c].addActionListener(gridListener);
    gridPanel1.add(gridButton1[r][c]);
    }
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(titlePanel, "North");
this.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
this.add(gridPanel1, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 400));
board = new int[10][10];//imagine board is kept below grid buttons and whatever happens on grid buttons i store that change in this array.
for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
for (int c = 0; c < board.length; c++)
{
board[r][c] = UNCLICKED;
gridButton[r][c].setEnabled(true);
}
board1 = new int[10][10];
for (int r = 0; r < board1.length; r++)
for (int c = 0; c < board1.length; c++)
{
board1[r][c] = UNCLICKED;
gridButton1[r][c].setEnabled(true);
}


}
class GridListener implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent evt)
{
if(count%2==0)
{

for (int r = 0; r < gridButton.length; r++)
for(int c = 0; c < gridButton[r].length; c++)
{

if (evt.getSource() != gridButton[r][c])
continue;
handleGridButton(r,c);
return;
}
}

else
{
System.out.println(count);


for (int r = 0; r < gridButton1.length; r++)
for(int c = 0; c < gridButton1[r].length; c++)
{
if (evt.getSource() != gridButton1[r][c])
continue;
handleGridButton(r,c);
return;
}


}

}
```

Comment: `actionPerformed1` can/is never called - move the functionality to the `actionPerformed` method instead

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: Stick to Java naming conventions - can you not see how `mPanel mPanel = new mPanel();` gets confusing?

Comment: If the problem was solved please post the solution as an answer or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Solved

actionPerformed1 can/is never called - moved the functionality to the actionPerformed method instead.
Just wasnt able to call the actionperformed even that's it.